# JavaFX WebEngine set document location

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I am sending a request to a website manually, and rendering the response's body in a `WebView`. For this, I've used the `WebView`'s engine's `loadContent` method:

```
String bodyOfResponse = ...;
myWebView.getEngine().loadContent(bodyOfResponse);
```

The problem with this, is that the `WebView` gets its content off a `String`, not a location, so it has no idea how to resolve relative links in HTML of the content I give it:

```
<span onclick="document.location.href='/'">Home</span>
```

The `WebView` can't find what that `'/'` refers to, since I didn't give the `WebView` content via a URL. Is there a way that I can set the current document's location (or baseURI, I've heard it called) so that my `WebView` will know how to resolve relative paths? (I know the original server's URL.)

I've seen that using an absolute location in the content, rather than a relative one, is enough to get the `WebView` to load the data at the location, but I can't modify the server and have it serve me absolute URLs in all HTML pages.

It would be splendid if I could just `webEngine.setBasePath(serverURL)`... but I can't. :(

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the WebEngine’s [Document](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#documentProperty%28%29) to finish loading, then add a [<base>](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#elementdef-base) element inside `<head>`:

```
String newBaseURL = "http://www.example.com/app";

myWebView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
    (obs, old, state) -> {
        if (state == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            Document doc = myWebView.getEngine().getDocument();

            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            try {
                Element base = (Element) xpath.evaluate(
                    "//*[local-name()='head']/*[local-name()='base']",
                    doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

                if (base == null) {

                    Element head = (Element) xpath.evaluate(
                        "//*[local-name()='head']",
                        doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

                    if (head == null) {
                        head = doc.createElement("head");

                        Element html = (Element) xpath.evaluate(
                            "//*[local-name()='html']",
                            doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
                        html.insertBefore(head, html.getFirstChild());
                    }

                    base = doc.createElement("base");
                    head.insertBefore(base, head.getFirstChild());
                }

                base.setAttribute("href", newBaseURL);

            } catch (XPathException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
myWebView.getEngine().loadContent(bodyOfResponse);
```